# Is it possible to verify another 3rd party app is connected to a google account?

Tags: google-api

My objective is to verify a 3rd party app (that uses google for auth/sign-up/sign-in) is connected to a google account, by calling a google API from my google app. Is this possible with the current google APIs? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this which leads me to believe it is not possible, likely for privacy/security reasons.

The best I've come across is a call to: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json which doesn't seem to return anything about connected accounts. And https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users which is for users in an enterprise domain which doesn't help me as my app is for consumer users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for you to know what apps a user is using on their account.  Even if its your own app there is no way of knowing. Unless the user has authorized you and you have an access token then you will know they have verified your own app.

Having an api which would tell us what apps a user has authorized IMO would be a bad idea.